# Insert NULL into foreign key when POST field is empty

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with foreign key name parent_id. i was try to insert the data like this:

```
 $parent = $_POST['parent_id'] ?? null;

        $data = [
            'name' => $_POST['name'],
            'skill_category_id' => $_POST['skill_category_id'],
            'parent_id' => $parent,
        ];
```

and in SQL i use code like this:

```
public static function update(array $data): bool
    {
        $sql = 'UPDATE skill_types SET skill_category_id=:skill_category_id, parent_id=:parent_id, name=:name WHERE id=:id';

        $db = static::getDB();
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bindValue(':skill_category_id', $data['skill_category_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':parent_id', $data['parent_id']);
        $stmt->bindValue(':name', $data['name']);
        $stmt->bindValue(':id', $data['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);

        return $stmt->execute();
    }
```

I already set in my table into null but it still gave me error:

```
General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'parent_id' at row 1'
```

how can i fix it?

Comment: `$parent = $_POST['parent_id'] ?? null;` - it is entirely possible that `$parent` will be `null` but the error message indicates that the column is expecting an integer. I believe you need to convert it to an integer and/or set the datatype; `PDO::PARAM_INT`

Comment: you need to set to 0 not null because the set-up is an int.

Comment: if i convert into integer it give me error SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`perwita`.`skill_types`, CONSTRAINT `skill_types_parent_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `skill_types` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)'

Comment: That is why i need to set it into null. not 0

Comment: `$parent = empty($_POST['parent_id']) ? null : $_POST['parent_id'];`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp it work thanks. u can put it on answer if you want so i can select it as the correct answer.

Comment: I suggest to change the title to "Insert NULL when POST field is empty". That might help other users with the same problem to find this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is `$parent = $_POST['parent_id'] ?? null;` Assuming your page is setup correctly, `$_POST['parent_id']` will never be `null` but may be empty (`''`). So the null coalescing operator `??` will assign `$parent = ''`. And that is not a valid value for int.

You could check if the value is empty:

```
$parent = empty($_POST['parent_id']) ? null : $_POST['parent_id'];
```